# Retain field name alias in feature class when exporting to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fields-attributes, export

I have a feature class in a geodatabase which I've joined a table to.  The table which was joined has field names >10 chars.

I will then need to export the feature class to SHP and once completed, the exported SHP will truncate any field names (and corresponding alias') >10 chars.

Does anyone know of a workaround/script that can retain/preserve field name alias' when exporting from feature class to shapefile?

Comment: Shapefiles can have aliases when referenced within a map document or layer file, but not standalone.  Remember that dBase is 80's technology; there's no place to store this info. My rule is to never save into shapefiles.

Comment: @Vince:  so there is no way to write in a script to re-populate ONLY the alias' values when exporting to SHP?

Comment: There's probably some way, but you'd need to manually write parallel data, then provide a means to read it. And in the meantime, numeric nulls are lost, wide strings are truncated, date fields are truncated, the attribute table is restricted to 4000 bytes/row...  Is it really worth using shapefile at all?

Comment: One option is to create a blank Shapefile with the desired field names and types. Use Append with the Field Mapper to define the source/target fields.